# Compute Score for parent child relation with multiple parent

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have this tree with multiple parents

Each Node have a weight and score. I am trying to calculate the composite function of each node

```
Team Score = ( (Node1 Result)*(weight1) + (Node2 Result) *(weight2) ) 
             ---------------------------------------------------------
                                  weight1 + weight2
```

I managed to calculate this function, but when the  node have multiple parents, my issue start

**Tree Structure:**
[image]

1. if  node type is **current list** = Look to current node, no need I go down in the tree
2. if  node type is **child , (child&linked list)** = ignore the current node and go down
3. if  node type is **(current and child ), (current and child and linked list)** = I include the current node
   and go down

**ALl Node Details in Team Table
Script**

```
CREATE TABLE teams(
   TeamId            INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
  ,TeamName          VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL
  ,TeamParent_TeamId INTEGER 
  ,TeamWeight        INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,TeamRollupType    VARCHAR(29) NOT NULL
  ,KR                INTEGER  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO teams(TeamId,TeamName,TeamParent_TeamId,TeamWeight,TeamRollupType,KR) VALUES (6399,'A1',NULL,1,'CurrentAndChild',0);
INSERT INTO teams(TeamId,TeamName,TeamParent_TeamId,TeamWeight,TeamRollupType,KR) VALUES (6400,'B1',6399,2,'ChildAndLinkedLists',50);
INSERT INTO teams(TeamId,TeamName,TeamParent_TeamId,TeamWeight,TeamRollupType,KR) VALUES (6401,'B3',6399,3,'CurrentAndChildAndLinkedLists',30);
INSERT INTO teams(TeamId,TeamName,TeamParent_TeamId,TeamWeight,TeamRollupType,KR) VALUES (6402,'B2',6399,4,'CurrentAndChild',10);
INSERT INTO teams(TeamId,TeamName,TeamParent_TeamId,TeamWeight,TeamRollupType,KR) VALUES (6403,'B4',6399,1,'Current List',80);
INSERT INTO teams(TeamId,TeamName,TeamParent_TeamId,TeamWeight,TeamRollupType,KR) VALUES (6404,'C4',6403,2,'Current List',50);
INSERT INTO teams(TeamId,TeamName,TeamParent_TeamId,TeamWeight,TeamRollupType,KR) VALUES (6405,'C2',6402,5,'Current List',20);
INSERT INTO teams(TeamId,TeamName,TeamParent_TeamId,TeamWeight,TeamRollupType,KR) VALUES (6406,'C1-A',6400,2,'Current List',20);
INSERT INTO teams(TeamId,TeamName,TeamParent_TeamId,TeamWeight,TeamRollupType,KR) VALUES (6407,'C1-B',6400,2,'Current List',30);
INSERT INTO teams(TeamId,TeamName,TeamParent_TeamId,TeamWeight,TeamRollupType,KR) VALUES (6408,'C3',6401,2,'Current List',40);
```

-- This is where Linked Lists are stored

```
CREATE TABLE linkedlists(
   TeamShortcutId            INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
  ,TeamShortcutFor_TeamId    INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,TeamShortcutParent_TeamId INTEGER  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO linkedlists(TeamShortcutId,TeamShortcutFor_TeamId,TeamShortcutParent_TeamId) VALUES (509,6402,6400);
INSERT INTO linkedlists(TeamShortcutId,TeamShortcutFor_TeamId,TeamShortcutParent_TeamId) VALUES (512,6404,6401);
```

Attempt

```
with CTE_UnionLinkedLists as (
select * from teams
union all 
select 
         TeamShortcutFor_TeamId as TeamID ,
         tm.TeamName,
         TeamShortcutParent_TeamId AS TeamParent_TeamId,
        --,tm1.TeamName AS StartName
        TeamWeight=tm.TeamWeight,
        TeamRollupType='Linked List',
        KeyResultScore=tm.KR    
from linkedlists ts
inner join teams tm on tm.teamid=ts.[TeamShortcutFor_TeamId] 
left join teams tm1 on tm1.teamid=ts.TeamShortcutParent_TeamId 
)

 ,rcte as
(
  select 
         t.TeamID as GroupID,
         t.TeamName as GroupName,
         t.TeamRollupType as GroupType,
         t.TeamId,
         t.TeamName,
         t.TeamRollupType,
         --Value
         case t.TeamRollupType
           when 'Child List' then 0 
           when 'ChildAndLinkedLists' then 0 -- if the current node must be ignored, then the current value changes to 0
           else t.KR
         end as Value,
         --Weight
         case t.TeamRollupType
           when 'Child List' then 0 
           when 'ChildAndLinkedLists' then 0-- if the current node must be ignored, then the current value changes to 0
           else t.TeamWeight
         end as WeightValue,

         --Value*Weight
         WeightedScore=
         case t.TeamRollupType
           when 'Child List' then 0 
           when 'ChildAndLinkedLists' then 0-- if the current node must be ignored, then the current value changes to 0
           else t.KR
         end 
         *
         case t.TeamRollupType
           when 'Child List' then 0
           when 'ChildAndLinkedLists' then 0-- if the current node must be ignored, then the current value changes to 0
           else t.TeamWeight
         end 
        

  from  teams t
union all
  select 
         r.GroupID,
         r.GroupName,
         r.GroupType,
         t.TeamId,
         t.TeamName,
         --TeamRollupType
         case r.TeamRollupType
           when 'Current List' then 'Current List' -- if the parent was the end of the sum, then it stays the end of the sum
           else t.TeamRollupType
         end,
         --Value
         case
           when r.TeamRollupType = 'Current List' then 0 -- if the parent was the end of the sum, then the current value changes to 0
           when t.TeamRollupType = 'Child List' then 0 
           when t.TeamRollupType ='ChildAndLinkedLists' then 0-- if the current node must be ignored, then the current value changes to 0
           else t.KR
         end,
         --TeamWeight
         case
           when r.TeamRollupType = 'Current List' then 0 -- if the parent was the end of the sum, then the current value changes to 0
           when t.TeamRollupType = 'Child List' then 0 -- if the current node must be ignored, then the current value changes to 0
           when t.TeamRollupType ='ChildAndLinkedLists' then 0
           else t.TeamWeight
         end,

         --Teamweight*Value
         case
           when r.TeamRollupType = 'Current List' then 0 -- if the parent was the end of the sum, then the current value changes to 0
           when t.TeamRollupType = 'Child List' then 0 -- if the current node must be ignored, then the current value changes to 0
           when t.TeamRollupType ='ChildAndLinkedLists' then 0
           else t.KR

         end 
         *
         case
           when r.TeamRollupType = 'Current List' then 0 -- if the parent was the end of the sum, then the current value changes to 0
           when t.TeamRollupType = 'Child List' then 0 -- if the current node must be ignored, then the current value changes to 0
           when t.TeamRollupType ='ChildAndLinkedLists' then 0
           else t.TeamWeight
         end

  from rcte r
  join CTE_UnionLinkedLists t
    on t.TeamParent_TeamId = r.TeamId 
)
select r.GroupName,
       sum(r.weightedScore)/SUM(CASE When r.Value <> 0 Then r.WeightValue Else 0 End ) as GroupScore,
       string_agg(case when r.Value <> 0 then convert(nvarchar(255), r.Value) end, '+') as GroupSumFormula,
       string_agg(case when r.Value <> 0 then convert(nvarchar(255), r.TeamName) end, '+') as GroupSumTeam,
       string_agg(case when r.Value <> 0 then convert(nvarchar(255), r.WeightValue) end, '+') as GroupSumWeight
       --string_agg(case when r.Value <> 0 then convert(nvarchar(255), r.weightedScore) end, '+') as GroupSumrweightedScore,
    --   sum(r.Value) as GroupSum,
       --SUM(CASE When r.Value <> 0 Then r.WeightValue Else 0 End ) as TotalWeight,
       --sum(r.weightedScore) as GroupWeightedSum
       

from rcte r
group by r.GroupName
order by r.GroupName;
```

Expected Result

```
+----------+-------+
| TeamName | Score |
+----------+-------+
| A1       |    30 |-- I have issue here
| B1       |  20.5 |-- I have issue here
| B2       |    16 |
| B3       |  38.5 |-- I have issue here, by chance I got same result because C4 is last node
| B4       |    80 |
| C1-A     |    20 |
| C1-B     |    30 |
| C2       |    20 |
| C3       |    40 |
| C4       |    50 |
+----------+-------+
```

In the code I am using for B1
I am doing like this

if the type has linked list I should not sum all weights and KR together

```
Wrong B1 =(2*20)+(2*30)+(4*10)+(5*20)
           ---------------------------- =18
               2+2+4+5
```

I should first compute B1 score which is 16 , then use it again inside its weight which is 4

```
correct B1 = (2*20)+(2*30)+(4*16)
             -------------------- =20.5
                     2+2+4
```

Comment: I don't understand how `linkedlists` comes in, what info does it represent?

Comment: @Charlieface its like a shortcut, when the user is at B1 level he can choose to also read data from B2. Then automatically this record will be added in linkedlists table tp reflect this scenario